# What is the meaning of "on the side of the future"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I just came across [this article](https://indianexpress.com/article/opinion/columns/myanmar-coup-humanitarian-crisis-refugees-tatmadaw-7251890/) titled "ON THE SIDE OF THE FUTURE".  Tried to google it, but couldn't find any relevant meaning of this expression.

Comment: I don't think it is actually an expression...but "on the side of" means aligned or allied with. So I would say that "the future" would imply a _positive_ direction, as opposed to the "past" when things were less than optimum.

Comment: What @Cascabel said. The usage has no real currency, but clearly it just means ***in favour of** the future* (as opposed to being reactionary / stick-in-the-mud [***Luddites***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luddite), who distrust the future).

Comment: Phrases like this are used to shame people that disagree with whatever the author is proposing. Certain political movements use this kind of language frequently.

Comment: @FeliniusRex Now that is quite interesting...are you referring to political movements in India?

Comment: @Cascabel I think you will find it where what is being proposed leads to a bright, shining future. I'm not aware of any geographic restrictions, though, it may be more common in some cultures than others.

Comment: Probably the most common scenario for this idiom is a game of sports.  Are you cheering for "the side" of the Surrey cricket team or the Sussex cricket team?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article you linked to is an opinion piece. The author is using "the future" to represent progressive policies such as democracy and humanitarianism. This contrasts with past policies of military rule, xenophobia, and discrimination.

"on the side of" simply means being in favor of something. For instance, if two people or groups are arguing, you're on the side of the one that you agree with.

So the article is saying that India needs to decide whether it's in favor of Myanmar instituting more progressive policies.